# run two Perl scripts one after the other

Tags: shell

I have 2 scripts which I initially wanted to join in a single script but it doesn't work for some reason. Anyways, once the first script is over, I'd like the second one to start automatically. How can I do that ? (I heard about shell scripts but I don't know to use it).
Thanks a lot

Comment: simply use an `;` to separate different commands: `cd .. ; mkdir tmp` will first go one directory up, then create a directory called `tmp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the simple task you want to do, your shell script would only need:

```
#!/bin/sh
./script1
./script2
```

After creating your simple script you need to make it executable by running

> chmod +x **your script**

Now you can run your new little shell script!

Answer (score 0):

What if the first one fails?

If that's something that needs checking you can do:

```
if script1
then
    script2
fi
```

or

```
script1 && script2
```

which is more idiomatic and succinct

Or even:

```
script1 && script2 || print "Big failure" 1>&2
```

as shell && has higher priority than ||, that reports the failure for either script's failure.